# What does "Apps management notification shown" mean in Google My Activity?

Tags: google-play-store, notifications, google-account

What does "Apps management notification shown" mean in Google My Activity history?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you clicked on "Details"?